# Synchronization with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

I am administering an office that utilizes Office 365 instead of the traditional Microsoft Office suite. While I have Azure ADSync set to run every hour, our Office 365 passwords haven't quite synced with our Active Directory passwords.

Case in point, we have two users who recently got prompted by Outlook to put in their passwords but had to put in their previous Active Directory passwords to advance.

If ADSync is running every hour, why did users still have to use old passwords to use Office 365? I'll be consulting Microsoft on this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

In AAD Sync on the Password Synchronization page, if you want passwords (hashes) to be synchronized, select the Enable Password Sync check box.

But AAD Sync is replaced by https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Sync runs User/Group (AD objects) Sync every hour but not password Sync. Password Sync runs 2-3 minutes after user changes password in Active Directory (On-Premise). You can definitely consult Microsoft for troubleshooting the Password Synchronization.

However there are some articles/prerequisites that you can look at:

-https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnectsync-implement-password-synchronization/

-https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2855271